# Using python to replace all links in HTML page to local addresses

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm new to working with html pages on python, and I am trying to create a very simple web-crawler. I've managed to download all links on the site I'm working on, but to go fully offline, I'm gonna need to replace all URLs on site to local addresses, for example:
I have saved the page "www.domain.com/news" under the next path : "myfile/sub0/0"
how can I use python to replace the URLs in each of the html pages I have downloaded to addresses as this?
I already got the list of links using this regex:

```
urls = re.findall('href=[\'"]?(http://[^\'" >]+)', htmlSource)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

Answer (score -1):

Read each of your html files from the directory, and perform a regex replace like below to change the urls into your one. Here is an example to alter the href links.

```
response = """
<a class="abc" href="http://www.example.com/abc.py">link a</a>
<a class="xyz" href="/xyz.py">link x</a>
"""
response = re.sub("(<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*['\"])(https?://www\.example\.com)?/?", "\\1myfile/sub0/0/", response)
print response;
```

Output:

```
<a class="abc" href="myfile/sub0/0/abc.py">link a</a>
<a class="xyz" href="myfile/sub0/0/xyz.py">link x</a>
```

Note, you may need to tweak the regex to suit on your need.

Comment: Btw, is there a way to change directory each time?
I mean, for the first file the path should be /sub0/0 and then sub1/1
re.sub can't help this time because there is no way to change the string at each iteration...